# How do I make slide in animations on page scroll?

Tags: html, css, scroll, css-animations

I have some HTML elements on a page:

```css
div {
  height: 200px;
}
#div1 {
  background-color: crimson;
}
#div2 {
  background-color: red;
}
#div3 {
  background-color: orange;
}
#div4 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#div5 {
  background-color: green;
}
#div6 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#div7 {
  background-color: purple;
}
#div8 {
  background-color: magenta;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>
<div id="div4"></div>
<div id="div5"></div>
<div id="div6"></div>
<div id="div7"></div>
<div id="div8"></div>
```

When the user scrolls down the page, I would like each element to slide from the side. Divs 1, 3, 5 & 7 should slide on from the left and the rest (2, 4, 6 & 8) should slide from the right.

I have no idea how to do this, but I have heard it can be done with CSS3 animations: the `@keyframes` rule. How would I go about doing these animations on my page?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need jquery for this:

```
$(document).on('scroll',function(){
// code here
});
```

Comment: how would I make the animations? how will each element sense that it is shown on the page? Please give more details

Comment: When you scroll you are going to have to get the scroll position using scrollTop()

Comment: For example : var sPos =  $(document).scrollTop();

Comment: Then set an if condition for each div, for example: if(sPos>100){$('#div1').css('left','100px')}

Comment: Take into account that defining sPos and the if conditions will be written in the on scroll function

Comment: so can you change your answer and add my code to it?

Comment: For now do $(document).on('scroll',function(){
var sPos = $(document).scrollTop();console.log(sPos);});

Comment: Do this to figure out when you want each div to move

Comment: this does not answer my question

Comment: '$(document).on('scroll',function(){ var sPos = $(document).scrollTop();console.log(sPos);if(sPos>100){$('#div1').css('transform','translateX(0);')}if(sPos>200){$('#div2').css('transform','translateX(0)')}});'

Comment: this is an example, it's up to you to see at what value of sPos you want each div to move, good luck